# JSON Decoding is printing an error, instead of printing decoded data

Tags: json, swift, xcode, parsing

I'm trying to get *author* and *download_url* from JSON **Array** below.

```
[
{
"id": "0",
"author": "Alejandro Escamilla",
"width": 5616,
"height": 3744,
"url": "https://unsplash.com/photos/yC-Yzbqy7PY",
"download_url": "https://picsum.photos/id/0/5616/3744"
},
{
"id": "1",
"author": "Alejandro Escamilla",
"width": 5616,
"height": 3744,
"url": "https://unsplash.com/photos/LNRyGwIJr5c",
"download_url": "https://picsum.photos/id/1/5616/3744"
} ]
```

Created an ImageStruct to convert the data of **JSON to ImageStruct** object.

```
struct ImageData: Codable {
var author: String
var dataURL : String
}
```

My JSON Decode handling is done in a func of a struct Called **JSONDecodeHandler**. The function that handles the decoding is called **jsonDecode** with an input parameter "**data**"

```
struct JSONDecodeHandler {

static let shared = JSONDecodeHandler()
let decoder = JSONDecoder()

func jsonDecode(data: Data) {
    do {
        let decodedData = try decoder.decode([ImageData].self, from: data)
        print("decodedData is \(decodedData)")
    }
    catch {
        print("error on decoding JSON")
    }
}
}
```

The input to this function is being given inside a struct called **APIHandler**

```
struct APIHandler {

static let shared = APIHandler()

private let jsonUrl = "https://picsum.photos/v2/list"

public func getDataFromURL() {
    
    guard let stringToURL = URL(string: jsonUrl) else { return } // Creating URL FRom string.
    let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: .default) // Creating URLSession
    let urlSessionDataTask = urlSession.dataTask(with: stringToURL) { data, URLResponse, error in
        
        if error == nil {
            guard let unwrappedData = data else { return }
            JSONDecodeHandler.shared.jsonDecode(data: unwrappedData)
        }
        else {
            print("Error in getting data from URL")
        }
        
    }
    urlSessionDataTask.resume() // Resuming the DataTask
}

}
```

The completionBlock of ***let urlSessionDataTask = urlSession.dataTask*** returns a *Data type* called *data*. This *data* is being the input parameter of the function *jsonDecode(data: )* of JSONDecodeHandler struct.

Lastly, The function **getDataFromURL()** of struct **APIHAndler** is being called inside my viewController's viewDidLoad as below.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    APIHandler.shared.getDataFromURL()
}
```

From doing these steps, What I'm seeing on my terminal is *"error on decoding JSON"* which I Wrote in JSONDecodeHandler struct in order to catch the error. So basically I can not decode a JSON Data. What am I Missing here?
Thanks

Comment: Replace the meaningless literal string `"Error in getting data from URL"` with `error` to get the very descriptive real error. And compare the  keys in the JSON with the name of the properties in the struct. They must match but they don't. And you can decode strings representing an URL directly as `URL`

Comment: what is dataURL? I haven't found this key in your response.

Comment: once remove DataURL and run the app it will give you author.

Comment: @vadian Thank you! I've missed that one. Printing out a string is meaningless now but currently just testing. Will handle that error for sure. Thanks

Comment: Even for testing purpose print **always** reported errors. DecodingErrors discover the issue immediately

Comment: Alright great to learn that. Will do it so. Thanks for advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name in your `struct ImageData` is `dataURL` but in the json you have `download_url` and `url`.  Those names have to match up for Swift to decode the json.  Chances are your `dataURL` field is empty.

Comment: Thank you! Missed that one and my problem has been solved. Appreciate it!